# AchartEngine Line Series and Point series

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I want to create a chart with one line series, and one scatter series or point series. You can say a scatter series is a line series with no line, but still has markers.

So i've been trying to set the line width to 0, but the line is still there for the point series

```
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(false);
    renderer.setLineWidth(0);       
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
    renderer.setPointStrokeWidth(2);
    renderer.setShowLegendItem(true);
```

I'd like to get result like this

[image: Chart Result]

Comment: No I don't think so. Why not using scatter chart only.

Comment: i can't use scatter chart because i need the time series and line series. I've added link to solution from achartengine forum. Need to tweak source code though

Answer (score 0):

This post answers my problems

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/achartengine/masschel/achartengine/oFlXCZqrWfU/PSaUC5atr_AJ

Basically we need to change some code in achartengine source code to make it not draw path if lineWidth = 0